# Btrieve Classes for .NET 8 - How to set localtion of DAT file in DDF

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration, btrieve

I use DbSetFileName function in Btrieve Classes for .NET 8 library to change the location of DAT files. Although the returned value is 0 after the function call. But when I check the DAT info in DDF then it not change

[image]

This is my VBNET code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim vbm As Compat = new BtLib.Compat()
        vbm.DDFDir = "C:\Users\vbnet-vm\Desktop\samples\vbSamp\DDF"
        vbm.DbLoadDDF()
        Dim mintTBNo = vbm.DbSetFileName("test", "C:\Users\vbnet-vm\Desktop\samples\vbSamp\OE_JYUH.DAT")

        MessageBox.Show("hellow")

    End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you specify a directory that is different than the DDF Directory?  The classes  or engine might be smart enough not to put a hard coded path in the DDFs if it's the same as the DDF directory.  WHat happens if you don't call the DbLoadDDF method? 
 The docs say the DDFs can't be open when changing paths. Using paths in DDFs is generally not recommended with Btrieve.

Comment: Because my DAT file is saved on the shared folder of a server, I have many software using these DAT files. So I would like to change the path of the DAT files in this DDF. Saving the path of the DAT file in the application config file is a good way for you to change the location of the saved DAT file that no need to change the source code

Comment: Really, every set of DAT files should have their own set of DDFs.  If you start changing the XF$LOC in the DDFs and are using a shared set of DDFs, you run the risk of using the wrong DAT file.

Comment: This was tagged as vb6-migration, is that relevant?

Comment: Thank you for your support, I have contacted the vendor and They told me that is an error of the library. They gave me a fixed dll file. It works better for me after replacing the old dll. Thank you very much!